# Unexpected end of JSON input error from DELETE method fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

[Here is the network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiUBy.png)

> I am constantly getting the "Unexpected end of JSON input" error in console when I run this code, but it works (the item is deleted when I refresh page, but it doesn't rerender on it's own even tho the state is chenged and throws this error when I run it)

> I checked if the problem is the type of id that I send when I call the function, and there is nothing wrong with it

```
 const deleteScreen = (id:any) =>{
    console.log(id)
    fetch(`http://localhost:5002/admin/example?exampleId=${id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token.token}`
    },
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.result)
        setAllScreens(data.result)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message)
    })
}
```

Comment: I think this is related to your server and not client.
check if the route works with the same id using postman, thunder client or something like that.

Comment: Well does your endpoint actually respond with JSON to a `DELETE` request? Please show us the network response.

Comment: The attached screenshot is not really helpful. Please click on Fetch/XHR tab and select the API Endpoint you are calling and share screenshot of that particular response

Answer (score -1):

It's look like there is something wrong with your `then` block. Try with just console `response` instead  `response.json()`. Or you can check with network tab response all well.